# What's the effect of `pass` in Python debug mode

Tags: python

I just found this phenomenon by coincidence.

```
mylist = [('1',), ('2',), ('3',), ('4',)]
for l in mylist:
    print(l)
    pass    # first pass
pass        # second pass
print("end")
```

If I set the red stop point at the first `pass` and debug, the program will stop here and the output is:

`('1',)`

However, if I set the red stop point at the second `pass` and debug, the output include the `end` in the last line. It seems like the `pass` avoid stopping at this point and just let the program run further.

I thought `pass` should have no real meaning, but it seems not. So how can understand the `pass`?

Thank you all

Comment: Did you mean breakpoint by "red stop point"?

Answer (score 2):

`pass` is just syntactic sugar for the parser to know that a statement is intentionally left empty. It does not generate an opcode, and thus, the debugger can't pause when it gets hit. Instead you're seeing it halt when the next instruction is executed.

You can see this by printing the opcodes generated by an empty function:

```
>>> def test():
...   pass
...
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(test)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 2):

`pass` doesn't do anything. It compiles to no bytecode. However, the bytecode to jump back to the start of the loop is associated with the line of the last statement in the loop, and `pass` counts. Here's what it looks like if we decompile it, on Python 3.7.3:

```
import dis
dis.dis(r'''mylist = [('1',), ('2',), ('3',), ('4',)]
for l in mylist:
    print(l)
    pass    # first pass
pass        # second pass
print("end")''')
```

Output:

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (('1',))
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (('2',))
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 (('3',))
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 (('4',))
              8 BUILD_LIST               4
             10 STORE_NAME               0 (mylist)

  2          12 SETUP_LOOP              20 (to 34)
             14 LOAD_NAME                0 (mylist)
             16 GET_ITER
        >>   18 FOR_ITER                12 (to 32)
             20 STORE_NAME               1 (l)

  3          22 LOAD_NAME                2 (print)
             24 LOAD_NAME                1 (l)
             26 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             28 POP_TOP

  4          30 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           18
        >>   32 POP_BLOCK

  6     >>   34 LOAD_NAME                2 (print)
             36 LOAD_CONST               4 ('end')
             38 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             40 POP_TOP
             42 LOAD_CONST               5 (None)
             44 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `JUMP_ABSOLUTE` and `POP_BLOCK` get associated with line 4, the first `pass`.

When you set a breakpoint on the first `pass`, Python breaks before the `JUMP_ABSOLUTE`. When you set a breakpoint on the second `pass`, no bytecode is associated with line 5, so Python breaks on line 6, which does have bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

pass is just a null operator, if your looking to exit the for loop, you need to use break. The reason you see the end of the output from mylist at the second pass is that the first pass just continues the for loop.